# Why does U-238 have a higher cross section for fast neutrons vs U-235?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Apparently the absorption of any neutron, even without attached kinetic energy, is enough to overcome the binding energy of U235, and fast neutrons scatter more vs thermal neutrons, so thermal neutrons are better for U235.

What about the structure of U238 is different vs U235 to not also scatter fast neutrons but to absorb and fission after absorbing those fast neutrons?

Comment: Seems like a even-even effect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#Pairing_term

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish: sorry, not seeing how the pairing term leads to the difference in sensitivity to thermal vs fast neutrons, can you explain?